# Parameterized Dominating Set

Tags: graphs, parameterized-complexity

What is the best algorithm to compute p-dominating set?

The p-dominating set problem is a parameterized version of minimum dominating set in which the problem takes a parameter $k$ also as an input, and the problem is now whether there exist a dominating set of cardinality at most $k$.

I know the problem is W[2]-hard so there is no chance of getting a $f(k) n^c$ running time algorithm unless the parameterized hierarchy collapses.

Comment: It _is_ W[2]-compete, yes, but if you know something about your input instances, it might actually be much simpler.  See a loooong list of problems and their _domination complexity_ on [graphclasses.org](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Domination.html).

Comment: Yes, I am looking for this problem on sparse graphs. I just wanted to analyze some known algorithm over sparse graph.

Comment: For sparse graphs it might be much easier (depending on your definition of sparse), as it even admits a [linear kernel](http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/frontdoor.php?source_opus=5732) (disclaimer: am author), and thus is very much FPT.

Comment: By the way, if the input graphs are degenerate, there is a very simple fpt branching algorithm: Pick a low degree undominated vertex, either that vertex has to be in the solution, or a subset of its neighbors. Mark dominated vertices, delete the low degree one and repeat.

Comment: yeah, I agree with the degenerate graph solution actually its exactly same  for planner graph as the planner graph are 5-degenerate. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can always solve it in XP time by trying all possible $k$-sets. In fact, it was shown by Pătraşcu and Williams [1] that there is no $O(n^{k-\varepsilon})$-time algorithm for $k$-dominating set for any $\varepsilon > 0$, assuming [SETH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis#Definition).

This is almost tight as for $k \geq 7$, the problem can be solved in $n^{k+o(1)}$ time (see [1]). As a special case, you can solve 2-dominating set in $O(n^\omega)$ time, where $\omega < 2.376$ using matrix multiplication.

---

[1] [Pătraşcu, Mihai, and Ryan Williams. "On the possibility of faster SAT algorithms." Proceedings of the twenty-first annual ACM-SIAM symposium on Discrete Algorithms. 2010.](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.215.3409&rep=rep1&type=pdf)